# Cant select face without vertices

Tags: faces

I cant remove this face somehow. Its not even selectable with A-Hotkey.
How can i solve this problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the face outlined in blue is part of a separate object from the one you're editing.  Toggle out of edit mode and select the other object, and edit or delete that.